# Core Image crop & scale image to size

Tags: ios, core-image, ciimage

I need to crop a thumbnail image of size (w,h) from ciImage of size (W,H). The thumbnail is cropped and scaled to fully fit size (w,h). What's the correct way to generate this thumbnail using Core Image crop & scale transform? In essence, I need implementation of scaledAspectFill using core image.

Here is my code:

```
    var ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
   
    let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
    let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)
    let imageSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    

    var scaledImageRect = CGRect.zero
    
    let widthFactor = size.width / imageSize.width
    let heightFactor = size.height / imageSize.height

    let aspectRatio = max(widthFactor, heightFactor)

    scaledImageRect.size.width = imageSize.width * aspectRatio;
    scaledImageRect.size.height = imageSize.height * aspectRatio;
    scaledImageRect.origin.x = (size.width - scaledImageRect.size.width) / 2.0;
    scaledImageRect.origin.y = (size.height - scaledImageRect.size.height) / 2.0;
    
    ciImage = ciImage.cropped(to: scaledImageRect)

   let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width,
                      height: size.height)

   //Do I need to scale again to fit 'size'??? If so, what should be scaling factor and what's the correct way to apply scaling transform that scales the image from center 
    
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    if let jpegData = context.jpegRepresentation(of: ciImage, colorSpace: colorSpace, options: nil) {
        
      //Write jpegData

    }
```

Is this code an overkill? Or there is a clean and better way to achieve it?

Comment: CIImage has crop and scale methods, so what's the problem?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is simple. Calculate the crop rectangle. Next, is there a need for scaling? Does ciImage automatically scale the image if we do ciImage.drawIn(rect) like CGContext counterpart? Or we need to explicitly apply scale factor?

Comment: You haven't given any context, but my experience is that it doesn't.

Comment: Ok let me write some code and post in the question.

Comment: Ok I posted some code. Please add/correct anything you feel is wrong

Comment: Ah. Well, you didn't say you were going to be calling `jpegRepresentation`. In that case there's no scale and no problem, the data is the data. So there's no scale issue. Notice that this is the rendering step and takes significant time (and should be performed on a background thread).

Comment: the jpegRep is not important, what is important is correctness. I need to generate a 500x500 thumbnail from both 1920x1080 & 640x360 videos. In the latter case, there may be upscaling while in the former case there will downscaling. Will jpegrep take care of this scaling? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to scale the image down before you call `jpegRepresentation`, otherwise you will just crop a small rectangle out of the original.

This code works for me:

```
let targetSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
let imageSize = ciImage.extent.size

let widthFactor = targetSize.width / imageSize.width
let heightFactor = targetSize.height / imageSize.height
let scaleFactor = max(widthFactor, heightFactor)

// scale down, retaining the original's aspect ratio
let scaledImage = ciImage.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleFactor, y: scaleFactor))

let xInset = (scaledImage.extent.width - targetSize.width) / 2.0
let yInset = (scaledImage.extent.height - targetSize.height) / 2.0

// crop the center to match the target size
let croppedImage = scaledImage.cropped(to: scaledImage.extent.insetBy(dx: xInset, dy: yInset))
```